# How do I make TexStudio find my latex distribution on Linux Mint?

Tags: texlive, texstudio

I installed TexStudio and TexLive. However, when I open TexStudio, it tells me that "No LaTeX distribution was found on your system". What do I need to do to be able to compile a pdf with tex studio? I would also be willing to use something like miktex instead of texlive if that makes it easier.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Usually it should find automatically, but if not, go to Options menu and Configure. Then, fill the path to binaries. In my case I have `/usr/local/texlive/2019/bin/x86_64-linux/pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode -shell-escape %.tex`. Your should be similar.

Comment: Hi Sigur,
I expected to find the "binaries" slot in Options -> Configure -> Build, but I only see Build and View, Default Compiler, Default Viewer, PDF Viewer, Default Bibliography Tool. Should I change one of these or where do I find "binaries"?

Comment: It should be in Commands tab

Comment: I can't see it there either. However I noticed that LaTex and PdfLaTex do not have a specified file path in the commands tab. Do I need to change those?

Comment: Yes, like my example.

Comment: Thank you, the error is now gone!
Should I somehow tag this problem as "solved" or something like that?

Comment: Don't worry. If someone post an answer, you could accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to the Settings in TexStudio, then Options -> Build and tick the box "Show advanced options". At the bottom of the window you can set the relative path where TexStudio is looking for the LaTex distribution. With most standard installations this is `/usr/local/texlive/2020/bin/x86_64`

Depending on your operating system and the year of your Latex distribution the year and the `x86...` part may be different.

PS: This is basically Sigur's answer from the comments with the important addition that you need to tick the "show advanced options" box.